# ValueError: time data does not match format '%y/%m/%d'

Tags: python

I am trying to convert a string to a DateTime object but an error occurs.

This is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime

string = "2021/12/18"

final_check_date = datetime.strptime(string, '%y/%m/%d')

print(final_check_date)
```

And the error is: ValueError: time data '2021/12/18' does not match format '%y/%m/%d'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just a format error. I have attached the code with its solution. a date string '2021-12-18' is parsed by this function if the format given is '%Y-%m-%d'.
[Code with the solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5TPq.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please **do not post code or errors as images**, but copy-paste them as text in your post! Then others will be able to search or run your code easily

Answer (score 1):

You <strike>may</strike> need capital Y when including century:

```
from datetime import datetime

string = "2021/12/18"

final_check_date = datetime.strptime(string, '%Y/%m/%d')

print(final_check_date)
```